# Are my methods being altered as they are executed?

Tags: methods, c++-cli, instance-variables

UPDATE: By combining the first two methods into one, my results have become reliable. So the issue was that the variables referred to in method two were uninitialized, even if the had been in method one. In what manner would I be able to refer to the value of double IntegralSlices in method one from within method two?

My assignment is to make a calculator that collects number of guests per party and requested pizza diameter. Then, it will calculate the number of slices per pizza and number of pizzas required to fulfill the order. The assignment requires the use of three methods.

I've tested the following code in the context of a button event handler with test data of 13.5 for diameter and 6 for number of guests, with the results checking out. Placing the code into the three methods and calling them with the event handler gives a seemingly random result each time. For each subsequent click of the event handler, the values increment slightly.

```
#pragma endregion
    private: Void GetSlicesPerPizza(double &pizzaDiameter, double &pizzaRadius, double &pizzaArea, double &IntegralSlices)
    {
        //calculate number of slices in a pizza of user-dtermined diameter
        double::TryParse(txtDiameter->Text, pizzaDiameter);
        pizzaRadius = pizzaDiameter / 2;
        pizzaArea = 3.14159 * Math::Pow(pizzaRadius, 2);
        IntegralSlices = Math::Floor(pizzaArea / 14.125);
    }

    private: Void GetNumberofPizzas(int &numberPeople, int &SlicesNeeded, double &IntegralSlices, double &IntegralPizzas)
    //input number of people at party, determine slices per person, number of pizzas needed
    {
        Int32::TryParse(txtNumberOfPeople->Text, numberPeople);
        SlicesNeeded = numberPeople * 4;
        IntegralPizzas = Math::Ceiling(SlicesNeeded / IntegralSlices);
    }
    //display result
    private: Void OutputPizzaData(double &IntegralSlices, double &IntegralPizzas)
    {
        txtSlicesPerPizza->Text = IntegralSlices.ToString();
        txtPizzasNeeded->Text = IntegralPizzas.ToString();
private: System::Void btnCalculate_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    //declare variables
    double pizzaDiameter, pizzaRadius, pizzaArea, IntegralSlices, IntegralPizzas;
    int numberPeople, SlicesNeeded;

    //collect user-entered diameter and number of guests, calculate pizza area/slices
    GetSlicesPerPizza(pizzaDiameter, pizzaRadius, pizzaArea, IntegralSlices);

    //determine how many pizzas are needed given number of guests and pizza size
    GetNumberofPizzas(numberPeople, SlicesNeeded, IntegralPizzas, IntegralSlices);

    //output number of slices per pizza and number of pizzas per order
    OutputPizzaData(IntegralPizzas, IntegralSlices);
```

Given the test data of 13.5 diameter and 6 people, the expected result is 10 IntegralSlices and 3 IntegralPizzas. The code executed exclusively in the event handler gives that result.

The methods gives any number of random result and then increment it, in one such test: IntegralSlices: 4.20327840774627E-293 IntegralPizzas: 5.70982877455134E+293

My suspicion regarding the incrementation for each click is that the variables declared under the method are being stored as instance variables and are being modified for each click, though the input values do not change. Second, I have no idea how to explain the inconsistency in the initial result. Given the test data of 13.5 diameter and 6 people, the result should be 10 IntegralSlices and 3 IntegralPizzas. The output from the methods gives me an unpredictable result for each initial click of the event handler.

Comment: This seems to be [tag:c++-cli], instead of C++. C++ doesn't have capitalized `Void` type, and `System::Object^` types.

Comment: You are using uninitialized variables.  It goes downhill when you use TryParse(), that is a function whose return value you do not check.  Required, a false return tells you that it could not convert the text to a number.

Comment: @HansPassant Are you referring to the variable IntegralSlices in the second method? I can see how it would all go wrong starting there. Is there any way to to refer to the value used for IntegralSlices of method 1 when method 2 is used?